# Strange class property assignment in Typescript (Javascript): '?='

Tags: javascript, typescript, expression

I've just seen the `?=` assignment expression in the class property declaration. 
Could someone, please, explain to me what it means?

I know about the new Optional Chaining (object?.prop) but this one is unknown for me. So I'm not sure if it's a mistake or it's a real language feature?

```
export class GoogleConfig {
  GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: string
  GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET: string
  GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL?='http://localhost/frontend'
  GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL_INTERNAL?='http://localhost/auth/google'
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

By default normal properties declared in `interface` are mandatory but you can declare a [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties) with `?:`.

```
class ShapeConfig {
    type: string;
    color?: string;
    width?: number;
}
```

Here, `type` is required, rest are optional.

Comment: Hi @Valibhav. Thanks for the answer but as you can see in the code we have '?='  and it's a bit different than the optional type. I can't find any example in the official TS doc about that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be optional class property with omitted type definition

```
export class GoogleConfig {
  GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: string
  GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET: string
  GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL?:string ='http://localhost/frontend'
  GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL_INTERNAL?:string ='http://localhost/auth/google'
}
```

Comment: the type `string` is implied by the type of the default value +1

Comment: Hi @Pavel, thanks for the answer. Where did you find this info? I'm wondering about some official ts doc/article, etc. I just couldn't find it.